# Red asterisk should not disappear in case of ellipsis

Tags: html, css, angular

I have a requirement, where the red asterisk should appear on right side of the label. Which works in normal case but when the text is long and an ellipsis is added to text the red asterisk hides.

```
<label>{{label}} <span *ngIf="required" class="required-star-new"> * </span></label>
```

// CSS

```
.required-star-new {
  color: red;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 18px;
  position: relative;
  top: 2px;
}
```

I want a solution where it should behave as shown in image below.

[image: Expected Output]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can consider `position:sticky` for this

```css
.required-star-new {
  color: red;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 18px;
  position: sticky;
  display: inline-block;
  right:2px;
  top: 2px;
  margin-left:3px;
}
label {
  display:block;
  max-width:200px;
  text-overflow:ellipsis;
  overflow:hidden;
  white-space:nowrap;
  border:1px solid;
}
```

```html
<label>some text here<span class="required-star-new"> * </span></label>
<label>very long long long long long long text here<span class="required-star-new"> * </span></label>
```

Or use flexbox but you will need an extra wrapper:

```css
.required-star-new {
  color: red;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 18px;
  position: sticky;
  flex-shrink:0;
  margin-left:3px;
}
label > :first-child {
  min-width:0;
  text-overflow:ellipsis;
  overflow:hidden;
  white-space:nowrap;
}
label {
  display:flex;
  max-width:200px;
  border:1px solid;
}
```

```html
<label><span>some text here</span><span class="required-star-new"> * </span></label>
<label><span>very long long long long long long text here</span><span class="required-star-new"> * </span></label>
```

Comment: @mulla.azzi this is should be a bug on FF. I face many recently when using a right sticky Will add another alternative

Comment: i observed that, if you increase the value of RIGHT property to more than 15px it shows up but it is shown over the text. So i think, it adds the ASTERISK but it is hidden by ellipsis.

Comment: it is working, not as per my expectations, but good enough to solve the problem. Thanks :)